# Changing the tile of a java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm wondering, how can I set the title of my Java JFrame GUI to something different later on? My program is a basic text editor, and I want to change the title to whatever you just saved your file as, or New File if you hit the New File button, or you just started the application up. The method I'm using right now is just a simple `setName("" + file + "");` where file is the File that was just written or read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setTitle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29) is what you need, not setName.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Frame#setTitle(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29) to set the title of your JFrame.

```
yourJFrame.setTitle("words.txt");
```